# Unicorn Engine - Emulate ARM and THUMB mode simultaneously

Tags: python, assembly, arm, unicorn

I am fairly new to assembly code, Keystone Engine and Unicorn Engine and I have an issue trying to solve a reverse engineering challenge.

I was given some assembly code which consists of both arm and thumb mode instructions (CODE16 and CODE32)

However when initializing the emulator there seems to only be two choices.
`mu = Uc(UC_ARCH_ARM, UC_MODE_ARM) or mu = Uc(UC_ARCH_ARM, UC_MODE_THUMB)`

When I choose one, only one portion of the assembly code is run. I am using the python binding. Am I trying to do something that is not possible or unsupported?

Comment: sounds like a broken sim, find another that works.  use the armulator.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialise in whichever mode as normal and inside a hook you can (in C):

```
static void hook_code(uc_engine *uc, uint64_t address, uint32_t size, void *user_data)
{
    uc_reg_read(uc, UC_ARM_REG_CPSR, &cpsr);
    int thumb_state = cpsr & 0x20;

    if (thumb_state){      // if thumb bit set...
    
        // Do Thumb things (e.g capstone Thumb mode disassemble)

    } else {              // Arm mode set
    
        // Do Arm things (e.g capstone Arm mode disassemble)
    }   
}
```